# order statistic of non-standard uniform distribution to beta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

If Xi∼U(0,1), then the jth ordered statistic is given by, X(j)∼Beta(j,n+ 1−j).

I however do not understand how if Xi∼U(0,θ) then
1/θX(j) ∼ Beta(j,n+ 1−j).

I have been looking for proofs online but i can't seem to find it.

Comment: If $X\sim U(0,\theta)$, then $\frac1\theta X \sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: how do I proof this or what can i read on to understand this, sorry i'm fairly new to probability.

Comment: Use the CDF, for instance.

Comment: oh i get it now, thank you so much

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: If your comments answered the question you should post them as an answer, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.